# Does setting a pointer to NULL affect original item you were pointing at?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, linked-list

I have a pointer to a node in a linked list:

```
struct node *temp = head.next
```

If I set this pointer equals to `NULL` such as:

```
temp = NULL;
```

will this also affect the node I was pointing to? i.e. `head.next` is now `NULL`?

Comment: Except for reference variables in C++, setting one variable never has any effect on another variable.

Comment: This question can be asked in reverse and it's essentially the same. `struct node *temp = NULL; temp = head.next;` does `NULL` become `head.next`? Of course not... That would make absolutely no sense.

Comment: Check out the analogy I used in my answer. :P :D

Comment: What happened when you wrote some simple code to figure this out? At least you would have seen what your implementation does.

Comment: Don't try to write multi-language source files. That is extremely hard work and any possible advantage versus writing single-language source files (various files rather than one) is very very minimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**will this also affect the node I was pointing to? i.e. head.next is now NULL?**

No.

---

Think of it this way. `head.next` is a variable holding a value (address). When you do

```
struct node *temp = head.next
```

Now `temp` also has the same value as `head.next`.

Later when you change the value of `temp`, why should the value held by `head.next` change.

---

This is the difference when you copy the value of a variable (which is happening is this case), and when you make a variable refer to some other variable, and change its content.

---

If you want the latter then you need a `pointer to pointer to struct node`

Something like

```
struct node **temp = &head.next;
```

Now if you want to change the content of `head.next` also through `temp` you can do by

```
*temp = NULL;
```

Answer (score 5):

No it will not. You have to understand the when you update a pointer you don't update its content or the memory location it was pointing to. For that you have to explicitly do it.

Now for your problem:

`temp` is holding an address of memory location where head->next resides. Something like (0x980901) setting it to null will only change the address it was pointing ie. now it will point to nothing.

Let me explain this to you using an anology. Suppose you have a piece of paper and upon it you have written address of your friends house. You erase the content written on this piece of paper does that mean you friend was moved out of his house? Obviously not.

In your case this piece of paper is temp pointer.

Answer (score 4):

No, because you didn't change the content of the pointer.

You just told him to point on something else.

[image: explain]

Comment: @Vucko @STF, the art is misleading in my opinion. It implies the `temp` is point to `head.next,` but actually `temp` and `head.next` are both pointing to some other node structure.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above answers are very well explained but may be confusing to people who have just started learning pointers.

Both `temp` and `head.next` are variables of type `struct node *`. Just forget pointers for a second and think about your question if both of `struct node *` variables where just `int`.

See this analogy:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
b = 0;
// a remains 1, b is 0
```

Now back to your question:

```
struct node* head.next = 1; // Some initial value

struct node* temp = head.next; // temp now has the value of 1
temp = NULL; // temp assigned the value of NULL, variable head.next remains unchanged
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magical or special with pointers, they follow the same rules as any other variable type.

Consider:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
y = 0;
```

The `y = 0;` will of course not change the value of `x`. The very same applies to your example.

I think you are somehow confusing this with changing the contents of a pointed-to variable. If you would instead do

```
int x = 5;
int* y = &x;
*y = 0;
```

Then `*y = 0;` would change `x`. But `y` would remain unchanged - it is still pointing at `x`